# Passing a curve into a GeoNode group?

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a Curve object which I would like to use as a base curve for a GeoNode group; essentially using an existing curve with the curve nodes. This feels like it should be a pretty common situation: wanting to use an existing curve as opposed to the basic primitives, but it seems impossible?

From what I can tell, when a curve is passed to the node group it is converted into a mesh:

[image]

And all that somehting like this does is create a mesh connector called Curve

[image]
[image]

One possible solution would be the use of the `Mesh to Curve` node, but that results in both quality loss and a curve that might as well just be a mesh (made of straight lines):

[image]

I can't even use `Object Info` to do this, it also converts the curve to a mesh

[image]

So, is there any way of doing this; using a pre-made curve with geonodes?

[image]

Comment: This is actually a very common situation, and when you pass a curve to *Geometry Nodes* (whether directly or via `Object Info`), nothing is converted. Curve remains curve. There seems to be a problem somewhere else. Can you share your blend file with us?

Comment: @quellenform is, as usual, correct.  I've tried curves as geometry input in 3.1.2 just now, and they work fine as curves.  Which version of Blender are you trying this with?

Comment: @MartyFouts According to the screenshot it must be at least 3.0, but even there there is no conversion of curves. Maybe there is another modifier hanging in the chain before GN or something...

Comment: Yep, I'm using 3.1.2, here's the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYtdYNnF12G4k-5A-SEMVkYlSg6aSgur/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Weird.  Your GN was screwed up but I didn't see the same error.  I deleted the GN modifier, added a new one, and everything is working fine in 3.1.2

Comment: @quellenform What do you mean? I imported this from an SVG, and it's made from bezier curves https://imgur.com/a/7MMtT6J . Surely following your steps is essentially the same as what would happen using the `Mesh to Curve` node, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blender's curve objects are a little confusing, because they really consist of two different things, depending on when you evaluate them.  They begin as one or more splines.  Then, various properties of the curve turn them into mesh: bevel, extrusion, modifiers that are not set to act on the spline, and, in your case, being set as a filled 2D curve.  All of these are properties that don't really make sense in a pure spline sense-- they make sense only as ways to turn a spline, which is just a line, into a mesh, a 3D collection of faces.

When GN is handed a curve object, it needs to make a decision about whether to interpret the object as a curve or a mesh.  Here, it's seeing all of the faces that have been created by the curve object being 2D and deciding to interpret the curve as a mesh.

We can tell GN we don't want it do that very easily, by setting the curve to 3D in properties/object data/shape:

[image]

We can see now that there is no warning on our curve to points node, and that points are being generated along our curve.